# WordPress custom field value exist checking

Tags: wordpress, field

I used a custom field with a regular WordPress post type, field named "website_url".

I want to validate submitting value exist in this field or not. Like : (http://www.example.com/) value exist in this filed or not.

I am using submit the post from frontend custom design.

Thanks
Aminul

Comment: **Welcome to Stackoverflow**, `to maximise your chance of getting an answer`, please **[Take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and read **[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. `Update your question` with just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read **[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**.